# What is an appropriate word for doing something to [ undo ] your deficiency in something?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

For example, a person who has an undergraduate degree in Electrical Engineering, and wants to apply for a Master's in Computer Science, has not studied some of the pre-required courses for an admission in the Computer Science program. In other words, he is deficient in some of the CS courses. For this reason, he takes a few extra short to ________ his deficiency.

**What word should fill in that blank?**

"I took the course titled ABC from the institute XYZ in order to _____ my deficiency, as I have not studied the course AZX in my undergraduate."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of possibilities:

1) **Correct**

2) **Remedy**  "to provide or serve as a remedy for"

Of the two, "to correct a deficiency" is rather more common.[image]
  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remedy%20a%20deficiency%2C%20correct%20a%20deficiency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cremedy%20a%20deficiency%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccorrect%20a%20deficiency%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. By the way, did you make that graph yourself? If so, what program did you use?

Comment: @Solace - That's Google Books' NGram https://books.google.com/ngrams

Comment: Often the adjective form _remedial_ is used in AmE to refer to classes designed especially for students who need to "catch up" to college level in a certain subject.  Remedial English. Remedial Math. These are for students who were admitted to the college despite deficiencies in their preparatory (High School) education.  A fun word for "knowlege you have to acquire before you can embark on a particular course of study" is _propaedeutic_.  If it's just one class that has to precede another in a series, it's [a]  _prerequisite_